# Using xslt to change an attribute value using arithmetic operations

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to bound the value of an xml attribute using xslt/xpath 1.0.  In this example, it would be the id attribute on the m_m element.

```
<blart>
   <m_data>
      <m_m name="arggg" id="99999999" subs="asas"/>
   </m_data>
   <m_data>
      <m_m name="arggg" id="99" subs="asas"/>
   </m_data>
</blart>
```

If the id is greater then 20000 it gets set to 20000.  I have the following xslt.  I know it selects the correct node and attribute.  It obviously is just outputing 20000.  I realize I should have some sort of xpath logic in there but I'm having a hard time developing it.  I have some big holes in my knowledge of xpath and xslt.  If you can point me in the right direction in helping me understand on what I should be doing I would really appreciate it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match ="m_data/m_m/@id[.&gt; 20000]">20000 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expected output would be

```
<blart>
   <m_data>
      <m_m name="arggg" id="20000" subs="asas"/>
   </m_data>
   <m_data>
      <m_m name="arggg" id="99" subs="asas"/>
   </m_data>
</blart>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following XSLT that gives flexibility to the attribute you want to change, and keeps everything else as it is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match ="m_data/m_m/@id[. &gt; 20000]">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">20000</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I actually tried this on an online xsl transformer and it gave me a wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match ="m_m/@id[. > 20000]">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">20000</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: Since I posted this, much better answers were contributed (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27161812/4256882) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27161808/4256882)).  SO won't let me delete this one because it was accepted, but in all fairness and for the sake of quality, I should encourage you to upvote the two aforementioned answers, so that they stand out over this one.

---

How about this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="m_m">
 <m_m>
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
  <xsl:if test="@id &gt; 20000">
   <xsl:attribute name="id">20000</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
 </m_m>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="m_data">
 <m_data>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="m_m" />
 </m_data>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/blart">
 <blart>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="m_data" />
 </blart>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I just tried [it](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) and it doesn't show anything. @xbug

Comment: That's weird, it works flawlessly with `xsltproc` (works [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html) too by the way).

Comment: Is your answer xslt 1 or 2?

Comment: Nevermind.  I just looked closer and see that it is declared.

Comment: I've just checked the [XPath V 1.0 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), just to be sure, paths are compliant.  The XSL stylesheet itself is declared as 1.0 and uses only common elements.  I suspect a glitch with w3schools online test app.

Comment: I think you are right.  Thanks for your help.  There is a detail I overlooked in my example.  The input xml has other data that is getting dropped.  What is the appropriate way for me to handle this even though you answered my question.

Comment: An example of this would be extra nodes under the root element blart as well as more nodes under blart that aren't m_m that I want copied.  I tried the copy identity with no joy.

Comment: I believe SO requires that we keep it to "one question per question" (and that we go easy on the comments ;).  Should you decide to open a new question on the site, I'd be happy to contribute if I can though.